# Acumatica / problem updating a free field in a closed invoice

Tags: acumatica

When I update the usrDocCom field, I get the error message:

Error: Updating  'SO Invoice' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors. Error: 'Project' cannot be empty.

I tried to remove the controls from the project field, but without result

```
    protected void ARTran_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);

   var row = (ARTran) e.Row;

    if (row != null )
    {
      PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(cache, row, false);
      PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<ARTranExt.usrDocCom>(cache, row, true);  
    }
}

    protected void ARInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (ARInvoice)e.Row;

  **Base.Transactions.Cache.AllowUpdate = true;** // permet de mettre à jour les informations libre des lignes
  
}
```

Thanks
Xavier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things...

1. be sure the project field has at least the non-project code assigned.  Usually the value is represented by 'X'
2. it is recommended that you create a workflow and set the enabled property as true, in the Completed/Closed state of the invoice.

Comment: You need to make sure to enable the cache for update as you doing on your code to edit the fields. Also, if the screen already has a workflow configured you need to take in consideration that maybe the whole screen is being disabled by the workflow on .WithFieldStates property by the status of the screen. About the project error, would you please put the stack trace?